# Reorder tabs in bootstrap-tabdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar

I have a page with a **navbar** and I'm using the **bootstrap-tabdrop** plugin that puts tabs in a dropdown list when there is too much to display on one line.
The objective is:

- When navigating through actually displayed tabs: nothing.
- When clicking on a tab that is in the dropdown list, this tab go in the first position in the navbar.

I have the following code.

**JS:**

```
$('#demo-tabs').tabdrop({position: 'left'});

function setActivePane(el) {
    console.log(el);
    var flag=0;
    var list = $("#demo-tabs > li").get();

    list.forEach(function(li) {
        if(li.id == el.id) {flag = 1;}    
    });

    if(flag == 0) {
        $("#"+el.id).insertBefore(document.getElementById(list[0].id));
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="max-width: 400px;" id="all">
    <ul id="demo-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-separated tabdrop" >
        <li id="nav0" class="active" onclick="setActivePane(this)">
            <a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="nav1" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li id="nav2" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li id="nav3" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li id="nav4" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a></li>
        <li id="nav5" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 6</a></li>
        <li id="nav6" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 7</a></li>
        <li id="nav7" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 8</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content gimmie-a-little-padding">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">This is tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">This is tab 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">This is tab 3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">This is tab 4</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">This is tab 5</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">This is tab 6</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">This is tab 7</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab8">This is tab 8</div>
</div>
```

It's almost working, my tabs go in the first position but, if I want to keep the same number of tabs outside of the dropdown list, I need to resize the page.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dredall/oc184eqe/) of this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope what you are trying to say is that when you select a tab from the drop-down it works but it appends to existing tabs and that disturbs your design so what i did is i added the `li` into the drop-down

```js
$('#demo-tabs').tabdrop({
  position: 'left'
});


function setActivePane(el) {
  var flag = 0;
  var list = $("#demo-tabs > li").get();
  list.forEach(function(li) {
    if (li.id == el.id) {
      flag = 1;
    }
  });
  if (flag == 0) {
    var toberemoved = document.getElementById(list[0].id);
    $("#" + el.id).insertBefore(toberemoved);
    $('.dropdown-menu').append(toberemoved);
    $(toberemoved).removeClass();
  }
}

function move() {
  reload("all");
}

function reload(id) {
  var container = document.getElementById(id);
  var content = container.innerHTML;
  container.innerHTML = content;
  console.log("test");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/leafn0de/bootstrap-tabdrop/master/build/bootstrap-tabdrop.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/leafn0de/bootstrap-tabdrop/master/build/bootstrap-tabdrop.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div style="max-width: 400px;" id="all">
  <ul id="demo-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-separated tabdrop">
    <li id="nav0" class="active" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li id="nav1" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li id="nav2" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li id="nav3" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
    <li id="nav4" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a></li>
    <li id="nav5" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 6</a></li>
    <li id="nav6" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 7</a></li>
    <li id="nav7" onclick="setActivePane(this)"><a href="#tab8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content gimmie-a-little-padding">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">This is tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">This is tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">This is tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">This is tab 4</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">This is tab 5</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">This is tab 6</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">This is tab 7</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab8">This is tab 8</div>
</div>

<button onclick="move()">Go !</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was too focused on the automatic use of tabdrop. I changed it a bit to append the last tab to the dropdown list.

Comment: @AGalliot, Thanks for useful. I'm wondering how I can archive the same collapse affect with jquery tab widget ? Thanks